# SQL Server Join Relational Table with a Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, relational-database

If I take out the WHERE clause the Join seems to work fine on glance... and the imageID 485 does exist... however, when I insert the `WHERE` clause below I come back with 0 results.

How do I add the `WHERE` clause to properly work with 3 tables joining?

```
declare @imageID int
set @imageID = 485
    SELECT Movie.movieID, Image.imageID, Image.filename, Image.imageFile
    FROM MovieHasImage
    JOIN Movie
        ON MovieHasImage.movieID = Movie.movieID
    JOIN Image 
        ON MovieHasImage.imageID = Image.imageID
    WHERE Image.imageID = @imageID --HERE IS THE CAUSE OF THE ISSUE
GO
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You're only selecting columns from the image table, so you could just do: SELECT imageID, filename, imageFile from Image where imageid = @imageid

Comment: Why all these Joins when all you need to output come from table Image?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, and your question is confusing. The **WHERE** has nothing to do with the **JOIN**--it simply limits which row(s) are returned.

Comment: If I am ever confused in a situation like this there are two things i would try to help me figure out what is going on: 1.try `SELECT imageID, filename, imageFile from Image where imageid = @imageid` (as suggested by @JohnBingham. 2. run your current query with select * and no where clause paying particular attention to the rows with your image in it.. making sure they are exactly as expected.. I don't know what step 2 is going to show but its always worth taking a look when you get stuck ;)

Comment: Sorry guys - I meant to include the Movie table ID as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something must be missing in the fields you are joining with. The record you see in the Image table may not have a matching imageID in the Movie table or it does not have a matching record in the MovieHasImage table. Doing an inner join causes the records to drop if they do not have a matching value.

The easiest way to solve a problem like this is to trace it back from where you know it exists. You can either do left outer joins on your tables or query each table individually to see if they have the value you are looking for.

Comment: Turns out this was user error - during the insertion of the data there was an issue where some of the imageID were not being inserted into the relational table